# Using splice with Breeze without setting linked properties to null

Tags: javascript, breeze

For some reordering code I call splice on an array of Breeze entities. Generally this works fine, but on removing an entity using `splice` from the array, its navigation properties are set to null. After adding the same entity back into the same array on a different position, navigation property seems to be restored, but the entityState has already changed to modified.

The responsible code seems to be [this call](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/ae3af9d4109f2dbb670a8a24dcacd96a663d47fb/src/a25_observableArray.js#L60).

Is there a way to move an entity in an array of entities to a different position without having the entityState to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As responded by in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/111): Workaround is to use a temporary standard array instead of an observable array, process the arrays using splice in the temporary array and write them back to the observable array.